# Equivalence of two algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, algebras

I am a theoretical physicist and in the context of my research I find myself with two algebras which should both correspond to the $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ Lie algebra, but I can't seem to find the isomorphism between the two. I use the following form of the algebra:
\begin{equation}
[L_-,L_+] = 2L_0, \quad [L_0,L_+] = L_+, \quad [L_0,L_-] = -L_-.
\end{equation}
The "other" algebra I have has the following form
\begin{equation}
[K_-,K_+] = 4K_0, \quad [K_0,K_+] = 2 K_+, \quad [K_0,K_-]= -2K_-.
\end{equation}
The statement is that the second algebra is also the special linear one. However scaling the $K_0$ generator to obtain the correct first commutation relation scales the other ones in the opposite sense $(K_0 \rightarrow \frac12\tilde{K}_0)$
\begin{equation}
[K_-,K_+] = 2\tilde{K}_0, \quad [\tilde{K}_0,K_+] = 4 K_+, \quad [\tilde{K}_0,K_-]= -4K_-.
\end{equation}
Either my brain is failing me and there is a simple isomorphism or the two algebras are surprisingly not equivalent. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you have a typo missing a minus sign on one of the commutators in the first line of equations.

Comment: Thank you Joshua I did indeed have a typo. I fixed it

Comment: Setting $K_i \mapsto 2 L_i$, $i = -, 0, +$, does the trick, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make $\tilde K_- = \frac12 K_-$, $\tilde K_+ = \frac12 K_+$, and $\tilde K_0 = \frac12 K_0$, and the "tilde $K$'s" satisfy the exact same relations as the corresponding $L$'s.

Comment: You're right, my brain was indeed failing me. Thank you so much!

Comment: @LuVa additionally note that simply replacing $K_+$ by $\frac{1}{4}K_+$ (or equally replacing both $K_\pm$ by $\frac{1}{2}K_\pm$) gives you the commutation relations of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ as they are usually given